# How can a homemade Haskell program to check if an integer is even be written?

Tags: haskell

I'm very new to Haskell, with my only prior programming knowledge being in Python. I'm trying to write a program for a part of a homework assignment that will take an integer *n* and return either True or False depending on whether or not *n* is even. I'm trying to use if/then/else as well as the built-in mod function, but I just can't quite seem to nail down the proper syntax.

```
iseven n = mod n 2
if n == 0 
then n = True
else n = False
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @SHiNKiROU Yes, sorry, I meant to include that in the OP. I'll correct that now.

Comment: -1: You should at least have had a tiny little look at some Haskell tutorial first. Like here: http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#ready-set-go

Comment: `isEven n =` starts a function definition. It's like `def is_even( n ) :`. Then comes the function body, which must be indented. see [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#Quicksort_in_Haskell), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_98_features#Syntax).

Answer (score 18):

If-then-else has the following form:

```
iseven n = if mod n 2 == 0 then True else False
```

See: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/If-then-else

Or just forgo the True/False return values:

```
iseven n = mod n 2 == 0
```

Or better yet, just use the `even` function [from the Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Real.html#even).

Answer (score 7):

You just need to connect the two pieces you have and fix up the syntax problems.

```
isEven n = if   n `mod` 2 == 0
           then True
           else False
```

But you don't need to compare `True` to `True`; you could just do the following:

```
isEven n = n `mod` 2 == 0
```

And if you want to get very Haskelly, you can make it pointfree:

```
isEven = (== 0) . (`mod` 2)
```

Comment: Also, `mod` is not necessary here as checking the least-significant bit for 0 is sufficient: `isEven n = n .&. 1 == 0`

Comment: @nemo ``Prelude> let isEven n = n .&. 1 == 0`` ==> 

``<interactive>:1:17: Not in scope: `.&.'``.

Comment: `.&.` is in `Data.Bits`

Comment: @WillNess `:module +Data.Bits` followed by `let isEven n = n .&. 1 == 0`. See the [Data.Bits module doc](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Bits.html#v%3A.%26.).